# Can we two-way-bind in custom directives?

Tags: vuejs3

I have the following logic, that I want to outsource into a custom directive. The variable `toggle` is a `Ref<boolean>`.

```html
<!-- This is the current situation -->
<div @mouseenter="toggle = true" @mouseleave="toggle = false"></div>

<!-- This is the goal -->
<div v-hover="toggle"></div>
```

The following code will register the directive, but the binding is only one way. That means, when I change the value to true or false inside the directive, it doesn't reflect on the actual DOM element.

```js
Vue.directive('hover', function(el, binding) {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => binding.value = true);
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => binding.value = false);
});
```

Is there a way to achieve two-way-binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives are meant to manipulate DOM mainly, since DOM and VDOM aren't very friendly, there's stated in the Vue docs that using directives should be avoided if a problem could be solved another way.

The main problem with your case that in templates all refs are unwrapped and directive gets values of refs, not refs themselves. The only way AFAIK to overcome this is to send a reactive object with our ref as a prop. Moreover we cannot declare that object in the template, because our ref will be unwrapped again before being assigned as a prop to the object.

So the solution (looks ugly in my opinion):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

const hover = ref(false);
const hoverProps = reactive({hover});

const vHover = {
  mounted(el, {value}){ 
    el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => value.hover = true);
    el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => value.hover = false);
  }
};

</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-hover="hoverProps" :class="{hover}">HOVER ME</h1>
</template>

<style scoped>
h1{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

I would say a "more native" way is to use a functional component (which is very fast) and VDOM (the bonus is multiple slot children, otherwise you have to repeat 'v-hover' on each of the children):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

const hover = ref(false);

const Hover = (_, {slots, emit}) => {
  const out = slots.default();
  out.forEach(vnode => Object.assign(vnode.props, {
    onMouseenter(){ emit('update:modelValue', true); },
    onMouseleave(){ emit('update:modelValue', false); }
  }));
  return out;
};

</script>

<template>
  <hover v-model="hover">
    <h1 :class="{hover}">HOVER ME</h1>
  </hover>
</template>

<style scoped>
h1{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the functional component approach. I will have a deeper look into that.